# Prototyped Method not being called correctly

Tags: html, canvas, timeout, game-loop

Really annoyed at this engine I'm writing, but that's fine, that's what Stack Overflow is for. So I have all my game "Entities" prototyping from an object:

```
    function Scene(name, description) {         // Initialize the Scene Object
        /* VARIABLES */
        this.entities = [];

        /* METHODS */
    };

        Scene.prototype.addEntitiy = function(entity) {     // Add an entity to this scene
            this.entities.push(entity);
        }
```

I have removed non-essential code (other Variables and Methods) for simplicity sake. As you can see, Scene is prototyping addEntity(entity). I instantiate TWO Scene objects (Scene1, Scene2) later in code. Scene1 doesn't seem to have a problem. Here is Scene2:

```
    // Scene Two
    var Scene2 = new Scene('Play Game', 'Actual game screen for playing Pong!');

    Scene2.addEntity(GameBall);

    Engine.scenes.push(Scene2);
```

Engine.scenes holds all scenes. Again, no errors at all with Scene1 (new Scene with one addEntity call). Scene two, however, insists this:

```
TypeError: Scene2.addEntity is not a function
```

Wtf, worked fine for Scene1? Also, Scene2 worked fine until I added a second entity to load (theoretically "identical" to the GameBall except for a few variable values). So, for thoroughness, I commented out the new entity as soon as the error showed up. Still not a function. I removed the new (offending?) line completely, still not a function. It's been like that ever since. Chrome and Firefox both report it's not a function.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mis-spelled `addEntitiy`.
<sub>*that was easy*</sub>

Comment: Gah! Did I really misspell it that many times?? Sadness... Stupid me. Almost comical, since it was "working so well" for so long on mispelled methods :)

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like your prototype method is misspelled. It should be addEntity, not addEntitiy.